# Doesn't contain regex in elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I'm using elastic and trying to find all document that doesn't contain some string.

I found out that I can do it with the regex `.*string.*` and use "must_not" query. but I really don't want to use it.

Is there another way? Thanks

Comment: For a better answer: describe why you do not want the solution you found so far

Comment: the query is very complicated and already nested 6 and even 7 times, so i don't wan't to make it more complicated than it is.

Comment: And what stops you from using a `must_not` with a `match` or `term` in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complement `~` with `ALL` flags should do it.

Something like `.*~string`.

[Read more here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)

Comment: @EranPinhas glad i could be of some help :)